# how to stop view disappearing when navigation controller left bar button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am rookie to iOS .In my child view controller i made some modification in data. I inserted a done button to store a data and pop the view controller from navigation controller stack. if i press navigation controller back button it automatically goes to back without saving data. if i made any modification in data and then i pressed back button i need show alert as "modifications are made are sure want to go back". if the user press the cancel button in alert view i need to stop view disappearing and still stand on same view controller.If anybody have the answer please help me.

Comment: It looks like you should present the view modally. That way there's no navigation bar or back button. The proposed solution works fine, but I think that conceptually the view should be modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a way to do it

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //back.png = your image name
    [myButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:customBackButton];

    }

    - (void)backButtonTapped:(id)sender{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"modifications are made are sure want to go back" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Go Back" otherButtonTitles:@"Stay Here", nil];

        [alert show];
    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
    clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]){
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }else{
            //Stay on the page and do something
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Comment: just add the left bar button (override) with yours.. and make a selector and do the alert part in that selector. The above answer is fine for your requirement

Comment: This is the right answer... but if i inserted a custom navigation back button it don't shows the arrow mark... so i need to detect back button touched and then i need to show alert view...

Comment: @karthikjin you must find a back arrow icon for yourself for example like in this 
[link](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/352020/arrow_back_icon#size=32).Download the back icon from link and rename it as "back.png" and add it to your project.Then you can see a back button.Make your back button's size 32x32 for now.

Comment: Glad it helped @karthikjin